# How do difficulty levels affect monster toughness?

Tags: bravely-default

The game says that monsters on Hard mode do more damage and monsters on Easy mode do less damage. What kind of actual percentage are we talking about, though? And are there any other differences?

Comment: The early bosses have about 33 percent more health on hard. I don't know much else though

Comment: When changing difficulty in game, the menu just says "Enemies are stronger". I've noticed a big increase in attack + magic strength, as well as a substantial amount of health. The enemies seem to still Brave/Default the same amount, however. Beyond that, I'd like to know as well!

Comment: In the JP version only, beating the entire game on hard (w/o changing difficulties) unlocked a [secret costume](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGHImswGLyQ) for Agnes (the Bravo Bikini). In the localized versions, you just get a HARD tag on Street/Spotpass if you stick with the Hard difficulty. It's possible to summon JP players (via Street/Spotpass) that have this costume in the localized version, but it will be censored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess the exact modifiers, but according to [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/729328-bravely-default/faqs/68431) (See "II. Walkthrough [W]"), the change is:

- Hard ~= 125%  for stats*, ~135% for HP
- Normal ~= 100% for stats* and HP
- Easy ~= 75%  for stats* and HP

<sub>*From the guide and my personal experiences, it seems that stats like Speed, Evade, and Aim don't change (or it might be miniscule).</sub>